# form submit required empty field shows message "Please fill out this field."

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Imagine having a lot of inputs fields, hidden blocks with input fields or tabbed content with input fields... When the form is submitted, if any required input is empty, the first empty input shows a message like "Please fill out this field." on Firefox.

How can i get that empty input field that shows the message (javascript/jquery)?

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="test" required>
  <input type="text" required>
  <input type="text" required>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. The field already shows its message.

Comment: You mean you want to get the actual empty field?

Comment: They want the elements (in JS) which are not valid.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: How can i get that empty input field that shows the message (javascript/jquery)?

Comment: @Seth thx, `checkValidity` is what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's Form validation API to determine which inputs are invalid. `checkValidity` specifically is what you want. It returns a boolean based on the input's validation constraints.

```js
const form = document.forms[0];
const required = form.querySelectorAll('[required]');
const invalid = Array.from(required).filter(node => {
  return !node.checkValidity();
})
console.log(invalid)
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="test" required>
  <input type="text" required>
  <input type="text" required>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

When run, `invalid` will be an array of inputs which are not valid according to your validation constraints.